# Programming square wave & sawtooth wave in R

Tags: r, waveform

I'm trying to build a function in R that represents square and sawtooth waves with 100Hz in range [0,1]. I tried this:

```
squarewave <- function (t) {  

  # 0.01  == 100Hz(=2Pi) -> 1 Period of the Squarewave
  # 0.005 == Pi          -> Half Period of the Squarewave
  # if t smaller than a half period -> 1
  # if t greater or equal than half a period -> 0

  if ((t %% 0.01) < 0.005)
    return (1)
  else if ((t %% 0.01) >= 0.005)
    return (0)

}
```

When I try to plot this function with:

```
plot(squarewave)
```

I get the following error:

```
> plot(squarewave)
Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,  : 
  'expr' has not been evaluated to an object of length 'n'
In addition: Warning message:
In if ((t%%0.01) < 0.005) return(1) else if ((t%%0.01) >= 0.005) return(0) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So why does this not work?

Comment: Post your error in english, not in german..

Comment: You aren't passing any parameters to `squarewave` when you plot it. You can't plot a function directly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a vectorised function to `plot`. So either use `Vectorize` to do this automatically, or use `ifelse` instead of `if`.

```
plot(Vectorize(squarewave))
```

or

```
squarewave2 <- function (t) {  

  # 0.01  == 100Hz(=2Pi) -> 1 Period of the Squarewave
  # 0.005 == Pi          -> Half Period of the Squarewave
  # if t smaller than a half period -> 1
  # if t greater or equal than half a period -> 0

  ifelse(((t %% 0.01) < 0.005),1,0)
}

plot(squarewave2)
```

To increase the resolution of the `plot`, use the parameter `n`, see `?curve` for details.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out and deleted my comment before I noticed you had answered. Anyway, I turned up `n` as you suggested and it worked fine. I did not know this before so I learned something today from your answer.

Comment: That's the point!
When using a ifelse-Statement the function appears as a vectorized function that can be plotted. Next, the plot seemed like a trapeze. To let the plot look like a real square wave you have to increase the n-Value of function plot.

Thanks to James!

Answer (score 0):

*I was wrong initially, wanted to update.*

**Unless** it is properly vectorized, you cannot plot a raw function and need to instead plot the output of the function. A simple way of doing this with your specific function is below.

```
sequence <- seq(from = 0,to = 0.01, by = 0.00001)
plot(sapply(X = sequence,FUN = squarewave),type = "o")
```

Comment: that's not right:
cos64hz <- function (t) {
  return (cos(2*64*pi*t))
}

works great with:

plot(cos64hz, type="l", xlim=c(0,1/20), ylim=c(-1,1.5), col="blue", ylab = "Amplitude", xlab="Zeit [sec]")

Comment: Could you be more specific? I produced a very nice square wave using it.

Comment: @AlexA. The function as written won't accept a vector as an argument, hence the use of `sapply()` to get a vector.

Comment: @TARehman: Oh yeah you're right. The internals should use `ifelse`, then a straight call to `plot` would be ideal.

Comment: @tbol Can you edit your comment into your question? It's relevant there for anyone who is trying to solve this. EDITED TO ADD: My guess is that the function you posted in your question is vectorized and R is able to interpret it; the other one is not and fails.

Comment: Sorry, in your comment, not your question, @tbol.